# No grub menu after 18.04 install

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2

Just installed 18.04 from a live usb.
Windows 10 is on sdb2, Ubuntu is on sdb3, sdb is a 256G SSD.
sda is a 1TB hard drive.
After the install I rebooted and it booted straight to Windows.
I booted back to the usb and ran boot-repair with 'install on all disks'.
Rebooted, now it only boots Ubuntu, no grub menu.
The bios boot option for usb includes the word UEFI.
boot-repair returned http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2prwjfBwYZ/

I can probably find a howto on installing grub manually but am unsure on a couple of points.
Have seen posts about UEFI being an issue. Dont even know what this means.
Which drive should I install grub to?
This is my first SSD, does this create any issues?

Im not committed to the install yet so can start with a fresh install from scratch if thats easier.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: While you have a new UEFI based system, you have both Windows & Ubuntu installed in the now 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. You cannot mix UEFI installs with BIOS installs, but should be able to dual boot. Is Windows hibernated? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Better to keep Windows boot loader in sdb's MBR, and have grub only in sda's MBR. If Windows is hibernated or needs repairs, then you can boot sdb from UEFI/BIOS to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you oldfred for your comment.
Yes, Windows was hibernated.
I was able to use ntfs-3g to remove the hiber-file.
I then booted into Windows from Grub and turned off fast-boot.
Hardly notice the difference in boot speed with the ssd.

Everything works fine now.